# Can the well-ordering principle of the natural numbers replace the principle of mathematical induction in Peano axioms?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, natural-numbers, well-orders

The well-ordering principle of the natural numbers states that the natural numbers are well-ordered through it's usual ordering.

I've already seen a demonstration of the principle of mathematical induction (PMI) through the well-ordering principle of the natural numbers (WOP), but there is something about it that bothers me: The only way I know to define the usual ordering of the natural numbers is through sum ($a\le b\iff$ $\exists c\in\Bbb{N}: a+c=b$), but the only way I know to define the sum in the natural numbers is through mathematical induction (more specifically, through the recursion theorem).

Is the PMI really needed in order to define the usual natural ordering? If so, would that mean a prove of the PMI through the WOP is redundant?

Comment: The question is, how do you define the natural numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, often we consider addition as being directly built into the structure of $\mathbb{N}$ - that is, as a primitive operation. (This is the line taken with *first-order* Peano arithmetic, for example.) If we do that, then the whole problem doesn't arise in the first place. Similarly, if we grant "$\le$" as primitive then we have the same fix.

But let's say we don't. It turns out that we **can** still define the ordering without any shenanigans using just successor: $a\le b$ iff for $a\in X$ for every set $X$ such that

- $b\in X$, and
- whenever $S(c)\in X$ then $c\in X$.

So we can in fact define the ordering, and consequently express WOP, using just successor alone.

---

The above has a slight annoyance: the definition of $\le$ we build from $S$ is **second-order**. Can we do better?

Well, not really. The usual ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ is **not** first-order definable in the structure $(\mathbb{N};S)$ of the natural numbers with just successor. First-order logic is actually pretty weak a lot of the time: we also can't define $+$ from successor and order, nor can we define multiplication from addition, successor, and order. It's only once we have both addition and multiplication that we can "implement recursive definitions" in a first-order way. Basically, if we want to avoid second-order definitions we need to equip the natural numbers with a richer "primitive structure" than mere successor alone.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the ordering as primitive. Say $(\mathbb N,\le)$ is an infinite well-ordered set where every element except the least has an immediate predecessor (this defines a unique ordered set, up to isomorphism). Then you can define the successor relation and prove the induction principle and recursion theorem. Then define the arithmetic operations.